# how to handle Rest API response might be anything as value might content plain text, HTML, Url, Hyperlink In Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, regex, angular

Response Type:

```
 1. "FieldValue" : "java is platform independent language"
 2. "FieldValue" : "<div>java is platform indepnedant language</div>"
 3. "FieldValue" : "https://www.oracle.com/index.html"
 4. "FieldValue" : "<div>https://www.oracle.com/index.html </div>"
 5. "FieldValue" : "<div> java is platform independent language for more info please visit https://www.oracle.com/index.html </div>"
```

---Angular Code ---

```
<div *ngIf='isLink;else other_content'>
  <a [innerHtml]="news.FieldValue" target="_blank ">{{news.FieldValue}}</a>
</div>
<ng-template #other_content>
  <div [innerHtml]="news.FieldValue">{{news.FieldValue}}> </div>
</ng-template>
```

---javascript function to check URL---

```
if(new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9]+://)?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@)?([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?").test(news['FieldValue']))
{
      this.isLink = true;      
}
```

I want if the FieldValue is link or URL then it is clickable and opens the link in new tab and if  FieldValue is plan Text/HTML then display in a normal div tag. I used RegEx to find the FieldValue contains URL or not but for 4 and 5 response type it not worked.

Comment: use `ng-if="islink"` inside the hyperlink tag, and `ng-hide="islink"` in the other div.

Comment: Get a better REST API which provides more predictable responses.

Comment: The code you provided only tests if a text contains a link but does not extract it from a text. Do you have a method doing the extraction? Do you use the same regex in it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved using

```
createTextLinks_(text) {
    var container = document.createElement("p");
    container.innerHTML = text;
    var anchors = container.getElementsByTagName("a");
    if(anchors.length>0){
          return text;
    }
    else{
    var plain_text = this.htmlToPlaintext(text);
    return (plain_text || "").replace(/([^\S]|^)(((https?\:\/\/)|(www\.))(\S+))/gi,
      function(match, space, url){
        var hyperlink = url;
        if (!hyperlink.match('^https?:\/\/')) {
          hyperlink = 'http://' + hyperlink;
        }
        return space + '<a href="' + hyperlink + '">' + url + '</a>';
      }
    );
  } 
  };
```

Thanks to all for your answers :)

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to write a regexp for a complex string, so simplify it firstly. in your case 4 or 5, you could do it step by step like following:

1. remove html tag
2. trim the string
3. using a simple regexp to check if it's a URL.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `ng-show` when it is `islink` inside the hyperlink tag, and `ng-hide` if it is a link inside the container:

```
<a ng-href="value" ng-show="islink" >{{value}}</a>
<div ng-hide='islink' [innerHtml]="value">{{value}} </div>
```

see [this plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/Pfd1dBnm06hqTLsOVo8V?p=preview)